# Fedex: want to use shipment creation without using in frontend

Tags: shipping, fedex

In our ecommerce system we want to charge for shipping for order total < INR 1000.00 and other are free. We do not want to have weight/distance based shipping charges.

Also we want to use Fedex shipment creation in the backend. As we shall be using Fedex as carrier.

Can you please suggest who to achieve this?